# Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-front-end

Prior to cloning the [substrate-front-end-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template) repo with tag ["monthly-2022-02"](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/releases/tag/monthly-2022-02) I installed the following since I was building it from a Dockerfile using pre-built Docker image node:gallium-alpine:

- Yarn 1.22.19 (running `yarn --version` outputs `1.22.19`). This was bundled with node:gallium-alpine pre-built Docker image.
- Node.js LTS v16.18.1 (matching contents of .nvmrc that includes `lts/gallium` and since the CircleCI .circleci/config.yml file is using Node.js 16.14)

But it appeared as though the repository required Yarn 3.1.1 (hence why there is a .yarn folder containing .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs,  package.json contains `"packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1"`, and a file called .yarnrc.yml whose contents include:

```
nodeLinker: node-modules

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs
```

But after you clone the repo and try to install dependencies with `yarn` it outputs error:

```bash
Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the issue involved upgrading to Yarn 3.1.1 before running `yarn`. Followed these [Yarn instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) to install its Corepack and the latest Yarn 3.1.1.

If I didn't correctly re-create the .yarnrc.yml file to include plugins and nodeLinker before running `yarn` then I would get error: `TypeError: semantic-ui-css@Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS#master: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'message')`.

Since we are using Yarn 3.x we still need to explicitly import plugins like [interactive-tools](https://yarnpkg.com/package/@yarnpkg/plugin-interactive-tools) into the file. It is also [necessary](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#step-by-step) to have `nodeLinker: <VALUE>` in the file.
So re-creating it as follows in the Dockerfile worked to adequately switch to Yarn 3.1.1 first and also resolved the error `Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)`, so it wasn't necessary to first have to copy across the /.yarn folder and .yarnrc.yml file from the host machine before running `yarn` (i.e. `yarn install`).

```
FROM node:gallium-alpine

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json .
RUN printf "Pre-built Docker image using built-in Yarn version: "; yarn --version

# it was necessary to install Git first since it uses that dependency
RUN apk update && apk add --update git && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN corepack enable \
    && corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate \
    && yarn set version 3.1.1 \
    && yarn plugin import interactive-tools \
    && echo -e "nodeLinker: node-modules\n\n$(cat /app/.yarnrc.yml)" > /app/.yarnrc.yml \
    && cat /app/.yarnrc.yml \
    && printf "Switched to Yarn version: "; yarn --version \
    && yarn install
```

Note: It would also work with Yarn 3.3.0 if the appropriate files were updated.

Reference: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/issues/259